# STS(Spring Tool SUite) Output console view disappears/closes automatically

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS(Spring Tool Suite) 3.6.4 version. For the last few days I am facing new kind of issue. Whenever I try to open console(Using Window > Show View > Console) console view opens for fraction of seconds and closes/disappears automatically. Same thing happens when error/info printed to console. It is visible for the fraction of seconds and closes automatically.

I am trying to see Tc server console. Currently for me there is no way to see the console view. Can any one have idea why it happens/ any solution.

Comment: I assume you mean "Window", not "Preferences".  What exactly do you mean by "closes"?  Do you mean the console view disappears, or the particular console you need to see goes away?  The "Console View" can show the console window for multiple plugins and embedded applications.

Comment: Hi Davaid, Yes I mean it disappears. The console view I was referencing is Tc Server console view. Updated the same in original post. Thanks

Comment: So you appear to be saying that in the bottom section, you see the "Console" tab completely disappear.  I find that hard to believe, but if so, I have no idea why that would be happening.

Comment: Yes David. I can't see the console tab. Even if I open it will disappear immediately.

Comment: Is there anything showing up in the Error Log view that could be related to this?

Comment: Sounds like something in view / perspective state has gotten screwed up. As some of that state is saved by Eclipse between sessions then this 'corruption' can continue to haunt you between restarts. You can try to 'reset' the perspective. Maybe that fixes it. If not, then maybe try something more drastic... a whole new workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with new workspace. May be the old workspace was corrupted.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Click mouse right button on the workspace, and click `Reset`

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the perspective to get the console.

Comment: Please expand you answer with example. It is not clear what `reset` mean

Answer (score 0):

For me, any console that appeared when running a Java application would immediately disappear.  Same git-repo/workspace, different computers.  What fixed that for me was quitting Eclipse, deleting the .metadata and .settings folders, relaunching, and re-importing my projects.  Only the workspace and my custom dictionaries survived.

Answer (score 0):

Some times because of unexpected short cuts Eclipse or/STS or due to some other issue

Allocate Console gets disabled. So we need to enable it

Run => Run Configurations > common Tab

Debug => Debug Configurations > common Tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6vqy.png)